# Why does screen IO get locked out until after Process.join()

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am learning about the Python multiprocessing library and noticed this curious {to me} behavior.  I am using Windows with Python 2.7 in Atom with the Atom Runner script execution package.  Given this code:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
def f(name):
    time.sleep(1)
    print 'count: ', name
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cnt = 0
    print 'Sleep'
    time.sleep(1)
    while 1:
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=(cnt,))
        p1.start()
        cnt+=1
        if cnt==2:
            print 'break'
            break
    p1.join()
```

The output looks like this:

```
count:  0
count:  1
Sleep
break
```

The print commands seem to get locked out until the multiprocessing completes, even though they occur earlier in the code.  Why is this?  Running it from a command window produces the expected output (counts after break).

Comment: Can't reproduce on Windows 7 Python 3; the counts print after the break.

Comment: Probably stdout buffering. Try calling `sys.stdout.flush()` before running the multiprocess code.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on OS X with Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Kurt identified the problem.  Calling sys.stdout.flush() before the .join() statement corrected the behavior.  Output is now:

```
Pool
Sleep
break
count:  1
count:  0
```